# Translation of slang *pass*

Tags: slang, cinema

I have a movie (The wolf of wall street) I'm translating (subtitling) with the dialog below, and I really don't have a clue what this *pass* is about. I'd appreciate a help understanding it.

> -I'm not gonna give you a fuckin' pass, just give me the case.
>
> -Oh, you're not gonna give me a pass?
>
> -Get out of here. Look, it's a figure fuckin' speech.
>
> -Oh my God, the Emperor of Foxville
>
> -Just give me the fuckin' case
>
> -came down from Foxville to give me a pass!

Comment: You might have asked this on [ell.se] – but we'll give you a pass this time ;^)

Comment: http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_does_the_phrase_give_a_pass_mean?#slide=2 http://www.idiomquest.com/learn/idiom/give-someone-a-pass/

Comment: @J.R. Why so this time? :)

Comment: @Kris I checked your reference link, and it's no great shakes. Who is this "authority" that proves the meaning of the idiom is the one given? I much prefer Susan's answer, in addition her examples are better and clearer than the ones provided on *your* link.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AFAIK, **to give someone a [pass](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=pass)** means to be granted a reprieve from something bad;  "given a pass"; forgiven for one's sins or indiscretions. [prior uses of pass](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=pass&searchmode=none) late 13c. *to go by (something),*  *to cross over,* from Latin *passare* "to step, walk, pass" is attested from c.1300. Not known when usage of example came into language.

> - He could have said a lot of other things in response.  Things like snap out of it, or that doesn’t give you a right to flip out...  But instead, **he [gave me a pass](http://www.gindivincent.com/2011/kitchen-pass/)**.  Full fledged acceptance of my condition which allowed me to be sad without having to explain it or justify it or apologize for it.  He didn’t have to do it.  Lord knows he doesn’t always **get a pass** from me.
> - I do try to be very careful where I step-  But I missed this rattler, and only the noise he was making gave me a chance to avoid it. The snake a least 5 foot long, 13 or so rattles, and very thick. However, **he [gave me a pass](http://pointoneracing.myshopify.com/blogs/news/7678771-mikes-corner-4-11-2013)** [the snake didn't bite him], and I get another chance to ride.
> - I got pulled over by a state trooper my second year of business and was missing a couple [MSDS sheets]. He started off as a ballbreaker checking each and every chemical. **He [gave me a pass](http://www.painttalk.com/f2/msds-changing-26155/)** when I pulled up the sheets on my phone and proved the chems were non volatile.

Comment: -1 Always substantiate your "answer" with a canonical reference. Opinions, are more appropriate in the form of comments, not answers. The OP's question is essentially GR, suffers only from lack of homework.

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/146723/translation-of-slang-pass/146724?noredirect=1#comment302406_146723

Comment: @Kris do you downvote every single answer that doesn't have a direct link to a source? I don't think you do. Is the user's years of experience and proven knowledge (see Susan's high rep) on the English language not itself some form of guarantee? If not, you should, in keeping with your justification, downvote about 1/5 (my rough estimation) of all the answers posted on ELU.

Comment: cont'd. While you're at it, you had better downvote Jon Hanna's post on this [question](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/146621/44619), and Stoney's answer [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/144619/is-there-an-english-idiom-for-bengali-idiom-wise-towelsman/144624#144624) too,  both are without a "canonical reference".

Comment: @Mari-LouA - thank you. You are very kind, and I appreciate it.

Comment: @Mari-LouA *The more that people vote on a post, the more certain future visitors can be of the quality of information contained within that post* -- http://english.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote

Comment: @Kris yeah, all very well but have you seen how low the visitor count has been recently? Only 63 people have clicked on this question, and presumably a maximum of six bothered to express a vote. One of them was me. Does that mean 60 viewers believed this answer to be lacking in quality? No, it doesn't. The answers which garner the highest number of votes are often single-word-requests, do they represent quality? Sometimes they  do, and sometimes they don't.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: I agree with Kris on this one. The Q really is GR (try Googling [give someone a pass](https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=cr&ei=x4naUtWFAaqr0AWs7ICQCg#q=give+someone+a+pass) if you don't believe us). In that context, assuming we're not going to just close the Q as trivial, I see no real point in "answers" that simply say what the queried term "means", with no supporting reference, no "etymology", no mention of the (slang) register, etc. I suppose the example usages here are "real" - but even they don't have links, so one couldn't check the full context for background info if needed.

Comment: @FumbleFingers it's not my question, and it's not my answer. I disliked Kriss's comment, and his/her motivation for downvoting is weak. You can hardly say the answer is inaccurate, or lacks examples. As for references, copy and paste a line or two onto Google and you'll soon find out where and what the sources were.  They're not made up.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - thank you, again, I've supplied the links for everything. This site confuses me, I'll admit. I'm told one thing by the mods, another by the users.

Comment: ... I suppose by *told one thing by the mods, another by the users*, you mean the mods worry more about "link rot" than the rest of us. I see even as I write this comment, you're fishing out the precise (and well-found) definition elements relevant to OP's context. That's what the mods like - even if the link goes bad, the crucial information will still be here.